# I have a blog and want to prompt the user to select a category they like and have that select a random blog post

Tags: posts, categories

I'm building a website that shows the best dj sets. As a feature I want to be able to ask a visitor for an artist/genre they like, which are the same as my categories/tags. Either through a dropdown or prompt and then show a random post within that genre. So the get a random DJ set they like and it starts playing instantly.

Is there a way to code this on a Wordpress website. I don't know where to begin would love some help! Thanks!

Comment: you need to break this apart into multiple smaller problems/tasks, this is too big to tackle on its own. E.g. "and it starts playing instantly" is an entire question on its own. Likewise implementing the dropdown list of genres/artists is a task on its own, as is randomly choosing a post. Ask separate independent questions for each of these. Some of these questions may need to wait until you have the answers for others. Asking it like this severely reduces the chances of an answer. Also you didn't share what you already have, e.g. do you have artists/genres already?

Comment: Hey Tom, thanks for the feedback! I will split this up into separate questions. I do have artist and genres already.